# Compile MySQL Server & CPP Connector from Source in MSVC2015

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to use MySQL C++ Connector in my Visual C++ 2015 project. I tried getting the built connector, but it was built with MSVC2010 and seems to be incompatible. I have tried literally everything: every download (binary distribution and sources), every install/extract path, every command in the Command Line, three MSVC editions (2015, 2013, 2012), I cannot get the C++ Connector to work. It's diving me crazy!!!

This is what I've tried:

- Building MySQL server and MySQL C++ connector from source
- Having MySQL Community Server 5.6 installed and building MySQL C++ connector from source

  - Via Visual Studio GUI (with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"`)
  - Via NMake with Visual Studio Command Line
- Having both MySQL Community Server 5.6 and MySQL C++ Connector installed from binaries.

All these methods lead to errors at some point, there are hundreds of errors at compilation. So what we (me and probably many other people need) is a tutorial-like answer on how to build/install the server and how to build the connector to work in MSVC 2015 with Boost.

Thank you very much for the time you will take to answer this!

Comment: MySQL connector c++ works pretty well in my computer with VS2015

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile the source for Connector/C a day ago with an older ,VS2013 x64, version of Visual Studio, and CMake 4.3.1 ...
Just cd to the source code folder in cmd.exe and do a cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" (if you need a 64-bit library)

It seems, the new changes in Visual Studio 2015 are breaking the C connector source code, I hope that MySQL team will fix this in a future release.

I think you can use Connector/C in your project, it won't make a large difference.